# Semi-Automatic Classification plugin: Cloud Masking errror

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, classification, masking

I'm doing Tutorial 2 out of the manual for this plugin as a GIS course lab exercise and I'm hitting an error when attempting to run the cloud masking function.

I'm using 3 bandsets of Sentinel-2 data (Bands 02,03,04,05,06,07,08,8A,11,12) of the same location on different dates. The cloud mask was converted to raster, but when running the cloud masking function I get the error below.

Error message: Warning [28]: Please define band sets with matching number of bands.

The cloud raster came from the same date bandset (bandset 1), there's no extraneous files (all .tiff format), the wavelength settings are correct for Sentinel-2, and the cloud masking page has the correct input band set selected.

- QGIS version: 3.10.1
- SNAP version: 6.4.2
- Operating System: Windows 10 x64

Answer (score 1):

Details: Turns out the error occurs when you change layer names. I'd renamed them for ease of reading, and so they no longer matched the layers listed in the band sets for the plugin.

Solution: Leave layers unchanged, no renaming, nothing.